# Is it possible to add a transient field to SORM?

Tags: sorm

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a field in a class that is not beeing mapped by SORM. I tried to add a @Transient annotation but ist was ignored.

I this part of SORM's paradigms to not do so?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. However, since I don't see how anyone could benefit from such a feature, I suspect you're missing something essential about concepts utilized in SORM, such as operating on immutable data structures only, the idiomatic "absence" of nulls and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was considering to use SORM to initialize an object that keeps runtime state that is never updated in the DB - maybe in variables even not managed by SORM. 

Thus the Object would be stateful but I would not need SORM to manage it. Maybe thats an absurd idea an I should use something else? Would SORM even care about my changes? 

Or should I rather use the SORM Object to initialize an object that is mixes in the SORM Object or keeps it as a reference?

Comment: SORM operates on immutable data structures only. Immutable structures don't have state as such, since they don't mutate. That's a cornerstone of functional programming and functional programming principles are a cornerstone of SORM. SORM doesn't manage any objects - it simply uses them as a lingua of communication with DB. You wanna update a value in DB - create a copy of a value you got from SORM with appropriate changes and `db.save` it. You wanna populate some mutable object with values from DB - just fetch the immutable value from the db and populate your mutable object with data from it.